# Manually adding values to charts in excel c#

Tags: c#, excel, charts, spire.xls

I'm working with Spire.XLS licenced pack and I need to find a way to set the values for a chart manually from a c# win form application, speaking about category labels to actual values to display inside, instead of being forced to use `sheet.Range[]`, or at least be able to use single cell values separated one from another from a sheet and use those like an "extended range" for the values any idea if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. See the following example which shows how to create a chart without using worksheet data range.

```
using Spire.Xls;

namespace Create_chart
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Create a workbook
            Workbook wb = new Workbook();
            
            //Get the first worksheet
            Worksheet sheet = wb.Worksheets[0];

            //Add a chart to the worksheet
            Chart chart = sheet.Charts.Add();

            //Add a series to the chart
            var series = chart.Series.Add();

            //Add data 
            series.EnteredDirectlyValues = new object[] { 10, 20, 30 };

            //Save the file
            wb.SaveToFile("result.xlsx", ExcelVersion.Version2013);
        }
    }
}
```

For more information, you can check this documentation: [Create Chart without Using Worksheet Data Range in C#](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.XLS/Spire.XLS-Program-Guide/Chart/Create-Chart-without-Using-Worksheet-Data-Range-in-C.html)